# How do I make a Squarespace footer have a background image?

Tags: image, background, footer, transparent, squarespace

HELP ME please.

In two areas of my Squarespace website I would like the footer section to be transparent. Aka in the ‘Answers’ entries, which are setup using a Blog style, there is a blue panel at the base. I would like the background image above it to continue to the base of the window. Same goes for the ‘Paintings’ pages where there is a white panel at the base rather than the image running behind the footer. The base text should float over the image. It’s setup as a Portfolio style. Please refer to links attached.

https://www.regardsfromyourfuture.com/future-answers/blog-post-title-one-b535f

https://www.regardsfromyourfuture.com/future-paintings/project-one-44zcm-57lgb-6glfy-p2f7c-nbdk9-76lc2-zh5z9

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS, added via Custom CSS / CSS Editor, will accomplish that:

```
/* Blog & Paintings Footer/Pagination */
.collection-60aef7b6d33efb6090ebf095 .item-pagination,
.collection-60b8480265d7df4bcf8f97ed .item-pagination {
  top: -2.5em;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

It targets those two "collections" specifically. It then sets the footer to overlap the section above it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Brandon, thank you for your reply. That has worked, however now the gallery images within the paintings section are invisible. You can still see the arrows to scroll left and right.

Comment: Also wondering if it's possible to duplicate a paintings page/entry which will have the photo background? When I duplicated "2050/1" it does create a new page/entry but it has a white background. I'd love it if I didn't have to add code for each new page. thanks again

Comment: I see what you mean regarding the images disappearing, @waynegurgh. It seems my original approach was flawed. Instead, see the updated answer above which is simpler, and less likely to cause issues with other sections of the page. Be sure to remove the previously suggested CSS from your site.

Comment: As to your other question about having a consistent background image across all posts, I believe that is possible. It would be done using CSS instead of adding the image via Squarespace's background image setting. I suggest asking a new question on SO.

Comment: Hi @Brandon That code has worked a treat! Thank you again. Problem solved :)